# NetworkManager and alias of lo interface became alias of team0

Tags: networkmanager

I want to create an alias of lo interface( I need it for VIP of keepalived).
But network-manager seems to create problems.
I have created this file

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo:0

```
DEVICE=lo:0
IPADDR=10.2.0.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
BROADCAST=10.2.0.255
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
NAME=lo:0
```

Then I set the connection up

```
ifup lo:0
```

The result is a disaster

```
team0              8c1d7e93-389b-4f61-b33d-ab9b6ca634b1  team      team0  
lo:0               54af739a-9533-7b7b-8fcc-691e69842b36  ethernet  enp1s0 
team1              af58780b-b280-49cf-b540-b55e49b2c52f  team      team1  
team-slave-enp7s0  b221675e-9604-4051-967e-a98b098c823d  ethernet  enp7s0 
team-slave-enp8s0  f8711dde-29bc-442b-aedd-2005888cf314  ethernet  enp8s0 
team-slave-enp9s0  67983ded-870e-4e5a-a284-9cfbcb6f1eb8  ethernet  enp9s0 
team-slave-enp1s0  9bea1e34-a555-450c-9d0e-10bad2ee99e9  ethernet  --
```

as you can see the slave of team0(enp1s0) is deactivated and lo:0 become slave(sic!) of team0.
If I remove the lo:0 all return ok

```
ifdown lo:0

nmcli conn show

team0              8c1d7e93-389b-4f61-b33d-ab9b6ca634b1  team      team0  
team1              af58780b-b280-49cf-b540-b55e49b2c52f  team      team1  
team-slave-enp1s0  9bea1e34-a555-450c-9d0e-10bad2ee99e9  ethernet  enp1s0 
team-slave-enp7s0  b221675e-9604-4051-967e-a98b098c823d  ethernet  enp7s0 
team-slave-enp8s0  f8711dde-29bc-442b-aedd-2005888cf314  ethernet  enp8s0 
team-slave-enp9s0  67983ded-870e-4e5a-a284-9cfbcb6f1eb8  ethernet  enp9s0
```

I have tried also to rename it to lo:10 lo:20 but nothing change

Comment: What gives `nmcli -o connection show lo:0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution, instead of using NetworkManager which don't work for this alias
I use the old good rc.local script and ip command
In this case I need a virtual ip address(is configured on keepalived proxy1 and proxy2) and is also "bind" to interface lo as alias on the two real servers, the two arp_ignore are necessary otherwise strange network problems happens.

```
vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local
#!/bin/bash

start() {
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore
echo 2 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_announce
ip addr add 10.2.0.4/32 dev lo label lo:0
}

stop() {
echo stop
}


restart() {
stop
start
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  start
  ;;
'stop')
  stop
  ;;
'restart')
  restart
  ;;
*)
  echo "usage: $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, when calling initscripts' `ifup` it merely calls `nmcli connection up`. That means, in these cases initscripts don't do anything relevant, except calling NetworkManager.

Anyway, initscripts support "aliases", which basically are additional IP addresses. These are ifcg-files with a `:0` suffix. I guess, if you used plain initscripts, this ifcfg- file might work. That means, if you set `NM_CONTOLLED=no` or disable NetworkManager altogether.

NetworkManager doesn't really support such aliases. It supports connection profiles (that basically correspond to a regular ifcfg file), and it supports multiple IP addresses per profile. But you can't split one profile into multiple parts, like what initscripts' aliases are. So, I guess this colon in the filename confuses NetworkManager.

The initscripts file format seems not so immediately obvious to understand. For example, seeing the file it's not clear to me how NetworkManager will interpret the file. But what matters at the end is that interpretation of the file. Look at `nmcli connection show lo:0`. Then it should be clear why NetworkManager behaves the way it does. I think the reason is that Networkmanager recognizes that this is an alias for `ifcfg-lo` file, but an alias ifcfg file cannot define a device name. At the same time, `ifcfg-lo` is for the loopback device, which is always unmanaged by NetworkManager.

It's probably a bug in NM, and related to trying to define an alias, which NetworkManager doesn't support.